# Why do SparkSQL UDF return a dataframe with columns names in the format UDF("Original Column Name")?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

So the dataframe I get after running the following code is exactly how I want it to be. It is the same dataframe as the original but all cells with purely numeric data have had all brackets and slashes removed (brackets are replaced with a minus sign at the front).

stringModifierIterator takes in a dataframe and returns a List[Column]. The List[Column] can then be used like in the command `dataframe.select(List[Column]: _*)` to create a new dataframe.

Unfortunately, the column names have been altered to something like UDF("Original Column Name") and I can't figure out why.

```
def stringModifierIterator(dataFrame: DataFrame, dataFrameColumns: Array[String], uDF: UserDefinedFunction): List[Column] ={
      if(dataFrameColumns.isEmpty){
        Nil
      } else {
        uDF(dataFrame(dataFrameColumns.head)) :: stringModifierIterator(dataFrame, dataFrameColumns.tail, uDF)
      }
    }

val stringModifierFunction: (String => String) = { s: String => Option(s).map(modifier).getOrElse("0") }

def modifier(inputString: String): String = {
  ???
}
```

This is what the column names look like when I use df.show()
[image]

Comment: Can you add how the output looks like (`dataframe.show())`?

Comment: Just added that to the bottom of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by explicitly naming the columns you create with the UDF in `stringModifierIterator` using `Column.as`:

```
def stringModifierIterator(dataFrame: DataFrame, dataFrameColumns: Array[String], uDF: UserDefinedFunction): List[Column] ={
  if(dataFrameColumns.isEmpty){
    Nil
  } else {
    val col = dataFrameColumns.head
    uDF(dataFrame(col)).as(col) :: stringModifierIterator(dataFrame, dataFrameColumns.tail, uDF)
  }
}
```

BTW, this method can be be much shorter and simpler without recursion:

```
def stringModifierIterator(dataFrame: DataFrame, dataFrameColumns: Array[String], uDF: UserDefinedFunction): List[Column] ={
  dataFrameColumns.toList.map(col => uDF(dataFrame(col)).as(col))
}
```